# Although the workflow field can be obtained by API, it is empty in the content editor

Tags: workflow

Although the workflow field is empty in the content editor,
I can get the value of workflow field by API.

> var varworkFlowBefore = targetItem["__Workflow"]

The default workflow for content, the workflow state contains values, but only the workflow fields are empty.

Is there a way to get the right workflow fields for such content?
I do not know why it is empty in the content editor although I can get it in the API.

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of empty fields in Content Editor? I have a suspicion that workflow is inherited and standard values are being used in your case...

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I'm sorry. I do not know how to paste the capture.
As you mentioned, it is "Workflow [shared, standard value]:".

Comment: What value do you get back in the code? And does anything appear in the content editor if you show raw values?

Comment: as mentioned above check the raw values. also make sure that your api calls are against the "master" db.? if you set the __Workflow in the standard values of the template, the  __Workflow field will not be updated in the item until you edit the item using non admin role. Basically the __Workflow field indicates the current workflow of the item. So the __Workflow field can be empty for new items, even though you set the __Workflow in standard values.